# Python network: How to check if only a single simple path exists between two nodes?

Tags: python, networkx

I am using `networkx.all_simple_paths(G,source,dest)` to find out all the possible paths between two nodes. I returns multiple lists.

Here is my code snippet:

```
for path in (nx.all_simple_paths(G,source=node1,target=node2):
         print path
```

This gives me multiple lists in which path is stored.
I need to find out if there is only a single path between a given pair of nodes.

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: `len(nx.all_simple_paths(G,source=node1,target=node2)) == 1`?

Comment: Doing this raises this error: `TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()`

Comment: Then try: `len(list(nx.all_simple_paths(G,source=node1,target=node2))) == 1`

Comment: @matt this generates the entire list, when ideally we should stop as soon as a second one appears.

Comment: If you do something with many paths, it will calculate every single one of them when it should stop after finding the second.

Answer (score 2):

Not the absolute cleanest, but here is a function that will look at the iterator.  If there is no first element, it returns `False`.  If there is a first element (i.e., there is a path), but no second element, it returns `True`.  If there is a second (i.e., there is more than one path), it returns `False`.  It never checks to see if there are any more.

```
def simple_path(G,source,target):
    iterator = nx.all_simple_paths(G,source=source,target=target)
    try:
        first_path = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return False
    try:
        second_path = next(iterator)
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    return False
```

Sample runs:

```
In [3]: G= nx.Graph()

In [4]: G.add_edges_from([(1,2),(1,3),(2,3),(3,4)])

In [5]: simple_path(G,1,2)
Out[5]: False

In [6]: simple_path(G,1,3)
Out[6]: False

In [7]: simple_path(G,3,4)
Out[7]: True

In [8]: simple_path(G,1,4)
Out[8]: False
```

Comment: Note - I think both Matt's and Prashant's solutions are better than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `zip` to match the first two potential paths together  (the contents of the list don't matter, that's why I put `_`). The length of the resulting object is the number of paths found:

```
paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G,source=node1,target=node2))
# True, if there was exactly one path, calculates at most 2 paths
is_unique_path = len(zip([_, _], paths)) == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if there exists a single path between node 0 and 1 for this graph `g1`, for example:

[image]

```
len([path for path in nx.all_simple_paths(g1, source=0, target=1)]) == 1  # True
```

You can extend this to check across all nodes if a particular number of paths exists and return a list of True/False for that particular pair of nodes.

```
import itertools
def number_paths(graph, number):
    # list of all possible pairs. NOTE: there may not be an edge between some pairs
    node_pairs = list(itertools.combinations(graph.nodes(), 2))
    num_path = []
    for pair in node_pairs:
        num_path.append( 
            len([path for path in nx.all_simple_paths(graph, source=pair[0], target=pair[1])]) == number )
    return num_path, node_pairs
```

So for the graph above you can do:

```
print number_paths(g1, 1)  # prints: ([True], [(0, 1)])
```

A better example is this graph `g2`:

[image]

Does there exist only a single path between pairs of nodes?

```
check, nodes = number_paths(g2, 1)
print 'check:', check  # check: [True, False, False, False, False, False]
print 'nodes:', nodes  # nodes: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Does there exist only 2 paths between pairs of nodes?

```
check, nodes = number_paths(g2, 2)
print 'check:', check  # check: [False, True, True, True, True, True]
print 'nodes:', nodes  # nodes: [(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Comment: Be aware - this method creates a list of all paths between the nodes.  This could be a combinatorial nightmare.  Once the second path is found, we know the answer is false, so there's no need to calculate the rest.

Comment: @Joel Good point.  Works nicely on toy graph examples.  I should probably fix it.  I like your solution +1

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by Joel's answer, avoiding generating more than two paths and branching via exception catching:

```
import itertools

def simple_path(G,source,target):
    iterator = nx.all_simple_paths(G,source=source,target=target)
    return sum(1 for _ in itertools.islice(iterator, 2)) == 1
```

It tries to calculate up to 2 elements from the generator.
It should return `False` is there are zero or two elements, and return `True` if there is only one.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `next` with its `default` argument:

```
def has_one_path(G, source, target):
    paths = nx.all_simple_paths(G, source, target)
    return next(paths, None) is not None and next(paths, None) is None
```

I think it's pretty readable and as efficient as you need: a graph has one path from source to target if there is a next path, and there is no next path after that.